# Regex to match one or both groups in specific order

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match and capture a pattern `/(A)/` followed by `/(B)/`. Any one of the two is optional but **at least one** must be present, and if both are present, they need to be **in order**. There's also some extra stuff `/X/` that must match but not be captured

Some things that **don't** work:

```
/X(A)?(B)?/
```

This doesn't work because it matches a bare `X` without an `A` or `B`

```
/X(A|B){1,2}/
```

This doesn't work because it can match `A` and `B` in reverse order, ie. `XBA`, which it shouldn't.

```
/X(A|B|AB)/
```

This could theoretically work, but the expressions `A` and `B` are actually very long and complex, so it becomes a nightmare to maintain and debug. (I used `A` and `B` as a stand-in in this question, to avoid the clutter)

So I need something that could **match and capture consecutive blocks with at least one being present in their specified positions**. Is there one?

Please match

```
XA
XB
XAB
```

and do **not** match

```
X
XBA
```

preferably **without repeating** the elements in the regex expression.

Comment: Why not store the expressions in variables A and B and use `"/X(" & A & "|" & B & "|" & A & B & ")/"` ?

Comment: Try `/XA(B)?/` or [`/X(A(B)?|B)/`](https://regex101.com/r/H2NlQQ/1).

Comment: @Wiktor, that doesn't match `XB`, which it should.

Comment: @Noldor I'm looking for a pure regex solution for reasons of portability and readability. I'd rather avoid using such methods as a crutch. But I understand that what I ask for may not be possible with pure regex.

Comment: So, why not match `XB` in `XBA`? Are you matching *whole* strings? See [`^X(A(B)?|B)$`](https://regex101.com/r/H2NlQQ/2/). It is not possible  to achieve what you want "without repeating the elements in the regex expression".

Comment: `^X(?:(A)(?:B)?|(?:A)?(B))$` would work but both `A` and `B` will repeated

Comment: Also, performance does suffer when you repeat long expressions ;)

Comment: @edgerunner: You are very much mistaken here. The length of the expression has little to do with the pattern efficiency. If pattern `A` can match at the same position as pattern `B`, it is true you should not use them in the alternation. All alternative branches must match at different positions. That is why I say it is better to use *real-life* patterns in the question.

Comment: @Wiktor, that was my observation, maybe it depends on the engine or the actual expressions that I use. In any case, I'd still prefer a clean expression if possible. Otherwise, Noldor's suggestion is always an option.

Comment: @edgerunner language pretty much matters for every regex question. See https://regex101.com/r/93khTA/1/ for an example using defined patterns, but that won't work for every regex implementation.

Comment: @Sebastian that looks promising. Maybe I can polyfill the missing functionality.

Comment: If it is any help, this is [just the `A` part](https://regex101.com/r/K9eOTW/7) of the actual expression I'm working on.

Comment: Write a regular parser or find one for your files.

Comment: I was actually hoping for some obscure syntax to handle this case. But right now, writing a parser with regex partials seems to be the only option. Define blocks and callbacks seem to be quite non-standard or unimplemented across regex engines. Maybe there will be an answer for this in the future.